# Adding 2nd browser to Socket.IO and the first stops responding

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm using the latest socket.io in nodejs and reactjs. Lots of code, the API can be seen here: https://github.com/DavidLozzi/virtual-happy-hour-api.

It is running on HTTPS, 443, locally, and when I connect 1 browser, it all works great!

Adding a 2nd browser and my first stops working. I've tried in different instances in Chrome. should this work?

I've since simplified my front end to a new project just to rule out my React nonsense, here's what my FE is now. Using a basic create-react-app

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';

const mySocket = io.connect('https://localhost/', { forceNew: true } );

function App() {
  const [convos, setConvos] = useState([]);
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState('');
  const [createdDate, setCreatedDate] = useState();
  const [convoNumber, setConvoNumber] = useState(0);

  const newConvo = () => {
    mySocket.emit('NewConvo', {
      convoNumber,
      roomName: `lozzi-${roomName}-${convoNumber}`, // actually this is convo name, but Jitsi calls it rooms
      lobbyName: roomName,
      loading: true
    })
    setConvoNumber(convoNumber + 1);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    mySocket.emit('SetRoom', 'testing');
    mySocket.on('RoomDetails', data => {
      setConvos(data.conversations);
      setRoomName(data.roomName);
      setCreatedDate(data.created);
    });

      mySocket.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('socket error', error);
      });

      mySocket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log('socket error', error);
      });

      mySocket.on('connect_timeout', (error) => {
        console.log('socket error', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>testing sockets</h1>
      <h3>Room: {roomName}</h3>
      <h5>Created: {createdDate}</h5>
      {convos.length} convos
      {convos.map(c => (
        <div key="c.convoNumber">{c.convoNumber}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={newConvo}>New</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I connect two browsers, whichever loads last, works as expected, the other doesn't update, however, the click event is recognized. If I refresh the first browser, it then works and the other browser no longer updates.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental in here.

Comment: Have you tried `forceNew: false` & added `/` to the end of your url: `http://localhost/` Also, your `https` is not SSL certified, so you should drop that postfix?

Comment: I just added `forceNew: true` in troubleshooting, I set to `false` but to no avail. Also added `/` as noted. I have disabled https locally, but that didn't help either. If https was a problem I'd guess it wouldn't connect at all or never work on one browser

Comment: Well then that rules out the easy stuff.  Next step I would go with is testing your code from the network side. Since your instance IP address is the same across two tabs,  the socket.io internals may think you disconnected and reconnected (similar to closing and re-opening your browser). So you may consider using another computer to connect to your socket instance by using `localhost:<port>` on the instance machine, and `http://<local network ip of the instance machine>:<port>`on the second machine. 
This would verify if you have a code issue, or simply a network re-mapping issue.

Comment: I have published this to the cloud and I get the same responses there. I'm now working on simplifying my nodejs to the barebones...

Comment: Made some great progress, I used the default demo from socket.io, and then attached this react app to it and it worked as expected. So I'll slowly add my components to it and see where I went wrong. I'll share my final answer once I get there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by not using `socket.emit` but instead `io.emit` in my API.

Went from

`socket.emit('RoomDetails', room);`

to

`io.emit('RoomDetails', room);`

Works like a charm now.